# How to programmatically upload file to Windows Server 2003 remote desktop

Tags: java, windows, rdp

How to programmatically and over the Internet upload file to a Windows Server 2003 remote desktop from within a local Java application given security credentials (username, password) and Windows Remote Desktop settings (rdp)?

Comment: Is mapping the remote directory out of the question? I personally doubt you can leverage the RDP session to transmit files using Java.

Comment: Why not using a shared-folder and a UNC-Path? There are meny waye to tranfser files to a remote folder.

Comment: @maksimov Yes, mapping the remote directory is out of the question. Me too. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

there are many ways to connect to a remote windows Server for sharing files:

```
File remote = new File("file:///server/share/path/to/file.txt");
```

Or use [JCifs](http://jcifs.samba.org/) ro connect to a windows-share.